# returning 0 if strings are same in c, where is happening in the code?

Tags: c, function, strcmp

I found a function which performs the same as `strcmp` but I was unable to see where the comparison `s1 == s2` is happening. I need help. Thanks.

```
int MyStrcmp (const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; s1[i] != 0 && s2[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        if (s1[i] > s2[i])
            return +1;
        if (s1[i] < s2[i])
            return -1;
    }

    if (s1[i] != 0)
        return +1;
    if (s2[i] != 0)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 5):

If `s1 == s2`, it also means that the length of the two strings are equal. Keeping this in mind, going through the for loop, none of the if statements in the loop are ever true. Therefore, we escape the for loop as `s1[i] = s2[i] = 0`, with `i` set to the length of the strings given. Now for the remaining two if statements, none of the conditions are true as `s1[i] = s2[i] = 0`. The code thus returns `0`.

Comment: Thanks HSK for the explanation, now, what is the purpose of the last If statements: if (s1[i] != 0) and if (s2[i] != 0)? I thought the conditions for those are already set on the for loop... Thanks

Comment: Consider a situation where `s1 = "edit"` and `s2 = "editor"`. Because the first four letters are same, the function does not return anything in the for loop, and when `i = 4`, `s1[i] = 0`, so the for loop is ended. But the two strings are not the same, and this is when the last two if statements come into play. (`s2[i] != 0`)

Comment: Thanks for the detail response, Appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

We can not see '==' indeed, because the function use exclusion method, this function trys to filter all the inequality situations.

The first half of this function: compare each char between s1 and s2, if any of char is not equal, the function finish and return corresponding comparison result.

The second half of this function: compare whether s1 and s2 have same length, if their length are not equal, then return corresponding comparison result.

At last, after it tried to exclude all inequality situations, its judgement is 'equal'.

Comment: thanks for the explanation of the whole code, this really helps